# Convert any[] to string[] | Convert List(any) to List(string)

Tags: typescript

Whats the easiest and simple way to achieve this in typescript?

```
['apple' , null , 2 , true] ==> ['apple' , 'null' , '2', 'true']
```

Comment: Are you trying to transform the array at runtime or the tuple type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

```
let strArr = arr.map(String)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=29&pln=3&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjBc0B2BPA2gXQgXgmg5FAA5Gj4QA0ESArsMJRAEyNgw0gYBQXokAzmwCCcHNDgA6ALbEAFAGU2ASyQBzAJQ8AxgHsk-HaAnAdq2YJgiY6oA)